# apparmor complain mode profile with null-

Tags: apparmor

After doing the following:

```
sudo aa-easyprof /usr/local/bin/my_proc  > usr.local.bin.my_proc
sudo mv usr.local.bin.my_proc/etc/apparmor.d/
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.local.bin.my_proc
sudo aa-complain my_proc
sudo aa-logprof -f /var/log/audit.log

sudo aa-stats
```

I see profiles with paths that include **null-**
its that a problem?
what is the meaning of that?
example:

```
22 profiles are in complain mode.
   /usr/bin/my_proc//null-/usr/bin/basename
   /usr/bin/my_proc//null-/usr/bin/dash
   /usr/bin/my_proc//null-/usr/bin/dash//null-/usr/bin/sed
```